# What does はくださらない mean?

Tags: translation

I am having problems finding a word in this sentence in the dictionary:

> 一体全体なぜこんなところにおいでになったのか、たぶん話してはくださらないのでしょうね?

Unknown word:
- はくださらない

The English translation is:
"And I don't suppose you're going to tell me why you're here, of all places?"

I get the meaning thanks of the translation, but I wonder which word はくださらない comes from.  Looking up はくだす gives no results.

Comment: The original title of this question  was “Word translation.”  Please imagine how many questions can be given that title, and make the title much more specific when you ask a question next time.

Comment: @oldergod: I rolled back your edit.  The point of the question is that the asker did not know that は was not part of the word.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I wonder then why both answers on くださる are so high rated.

Comment: @oldergod: Then you should read the answers more carefully.  Both answers explain that はくださらない is not a single word but a combination of は and くださらない.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

くださらない(下さらない) is the negative form of くださる. 
くださる(下さる) is the honorific form of くれる. 
So 話して(+は)+くださらない is the negative form of 話して+くださる and 話して+くださる is the honorific of 話して+くれる. 
(The negative form of 話して+くれる is 話して(+は)+くれない.) 
The は is the particle([係助詞]{かかりじょし}) that comes with the negative ない (I think)...^^;
Someone correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: +1 for relating くださる to くれる

Answer (score 6):

The verb you're looking for is くださる

話してはくださらない

What's going on here is te-form + は(the particle) + くださる