Understanding 頼まれちゃくれねえか
Copied from the recently deleted question from @whatyouexpect because I want to know the answer.

Character [A] is wounded in a color-gang fight, asks friend [B] if they can take them to the hospital:

[A] なあ 病院に運ぶなら
１つだけ頼まれちゃくれねえかな
[B] 何？
[A] 運ぶのは来良(らいら)総合病院にしてくれ
待ってる女がいるんだ
頼むよ

I understand that ちゃくれねえかな holds two contractions, the fuller form being:

頼まれてはくれないかな

It doesn't seem like ては though means "if" here like in this question, は seems to have more of a contrastive function.
Where I am confused is the reason for the passive here. This is not a polite passive, so it seems to work out as:
"I wonder if you wouldn't be entrusted to just one thing for me"
Is this a usual usage of the passive? The use of the 頼まれて is putting the perspective on character B, with くれる marking it as beneficial to A, which makes sense logically, but I wonder if this is a normal thing to do (affix a receiver verb to a passive as a request)?.
If it is, are there any nuances to this kind of request?
Also, searching "頼まれてはくれない" as a fuller form yields about 80,000 results, which doesn't seem like too much for a high-use verb like 頼む.

Based on my understanding 頼まれてはくれないかな has similar meaning to 頼まれてくれないかな. I think it can be understood as "won't you get requested for me"?

頼まれてはくれないかな has similar meaning to 頼まれてくれないかな. <- Right. は often comes with negative ない. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9842/9831 The negative form of 話して+くれる is 話して(+は)+くれない The は is the particle that comes with the negative ない

This is a natural phrase, and it is one of the many ways of asking something in Japanese. The non-passive version is something like 俺の頼みを聞いちゃくれねえかな, which of course is also natural, but may sound slightly more blunt. Compared to the non-passive version, the passive version sounds a little more indirect and politer to me, because the passive form indicates the speaker understands the listener might be bothered by the request (remember that Japanese passive voice is often associated with 迷惑).
English speakers sometimes ask for something using "Would you mind if ...". A similar type of consideration for the listener's feelings may be expressed by this passive voice.
